# 404 page not working with permalink: pretty using GitHub Pages + Jekyll

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, jekyll, github-pages

In my `config.yml` I have permalinks set to pretty:

`permalink: pretty`

When I do this, my 404.html page is no longer showing up on my website (hosted on GitHub pages) when there is a 404 error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is add this in the front-matter of your 404.html file:

```
---
permalink: /404.html
---
```

See https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site/